# Data table to getAttribute value in JS LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

Get attribute key value returns `null` value. Can anyone please help me on this?

```
<div class="slds-p-top_x-large">
                        <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={studentdata} columns={studentColumns} data-record-id={Id}
                            draft-values={draftValues} hide-checkbox-column="true" resize-column-disabled="true"
                             onsave={handleStudentSave} onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
                        </lightning-datatable>                             
                    </div>



handleRowAction (event){
alert('Hello'   +  event.target.getAttribute("data-record-id"));
//alert('Hello'   +  event.target.getAttribute("key-field"));
}
```

Comment: try with `row = event.detail.row`

Comment: Undefined value

Answer (score 2):

record id can be accessed using dataset `event.target.dataset.recordId`.
record-id translates to recordId. The kebab cased 'data-' attributes from html translates to camel-cased dataset property names in JS. For example, if it was 'data-new-email-id' it translates to 'newEmailId' in JS.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to achieve, but will cover the possible outcomes you are trying to find.

### Getting the record id of a row on rowaction

Check out the example in the lightning-datatable [Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) and related [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/8342b2812fa2b8a80aecde269c3530aa91a56694/edit).

The gist of it is you would interrogate `event.detail` to get the row attributes (e.g. ID) as the `rowaction` events are dispatched from the rows which are effectively children of the datatable component. This concept is explained in detail in [Create and Dispatch Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch).

In your use case, you would get the record Id of each row using `event.detail.row.id`:

```
handleRowAction(event) {
    const recordId = event.detail.row.id;
}
```

### Getting the key field used in the datatable

I suggest declaring a property for the key-field attribute in the module. This way you can use it in the module for other purposes.

JS:

```
keyField = 'Id';
```

HTML:

```
<lightning-datatable key-field={keyField} ...></lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns} hide-checkbox-column="true"
        onrowaction={handleRowActions} ></lightning-datatable>
```

---

```
handleRowActions(event){
        let actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        console.log('Action Name '+ actionName);       
        let row = event.detail.row;
        console.log('selected Row '+ JSON.stringify(row));
        let rowId = event.detail.row.Id;
        console.log('selected Row '+ rowId);
    }
```

Use event.detail.row : it will return row record.
use event.deail.row.Id : it will return row Id